# ISO-8859-2 Encoding on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, encoding, iso-8859-2

I'm writing a small RSS reader for a Hungarian site, which uses ISO-8859-2 for encoding.

Neither the RSS header nor the Content-Type header defines the encoding, so I'd like to set it manually.
The only issue is, HttpClient won't let me.

If I use HttpClient.GetStringAsync(URI), it returns the string in UTF-16 encoding, which screws up the special characters (no conversion, just dumping it into the UTF-16 expecting String container).

If I use HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync, then try to process it with XElement.Load(Stream), I get a weird error about not being able to encode ISO-8859-2 on the device, as it is not supported.

This is a Universal App, so I have a W8.1 counterpart too - which works flawlessly with the exact same code.

Is there any solution to do the conversion on WP8.1 too?

Comment: What's the weird error look like? Doesn't WP8.1 have iso-8859-2 decoding capabilities? Because if it doesn't, then it sounds like you're out of luck unless you write your own iso-8859-2 decoder. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484076/convert-encoding-on-windows-phone-8-1

Comment: Microsoft aggressively removed support for the legacy 8-bit encodings in WinRT.  Good riddance.  Ping the site owner and suggest him to move into the 21st century :)

Comment: They will hardly do so. Their RSS is set up, and they won't spend a dime changing it.

Comment: bzlm - the MSP Toolkit suggested in that question solved the problem (even though it needed some reconstruction to work on wp81 targets).